# blank screen when i execute simple Kivy code

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to kivy and using some tutorials but i only get black screen while on the videos developers get their widget on the screen.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __int__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__int__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Name: "))
        self.name = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.name)

        self.add_widget(Label(text="last name : "))
        self.lastName = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.lastname)

        self.add_widget(Label(text="email: "))
        self.emailName = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.emailname)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some spelling errors in the code.
The first is about the `__init__` function that you spelled `__int__`
You also use a different variable to assign a widget and a similar one (but *different*) for adding it (e.g. `self.lastName = TextInput(multiline=False)` and `self.add_widget(self.lastname)`)
This code should work:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Name: "))
        self.name = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.name)

        self.add_widget(Label(text="last name : "))
        self.lastName = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.lastName)

        self.add_widget(Label(text="email: "))
        self.emailName = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.emailName)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks > a lot .for your time .. . i was soo laughing at my mistake now . i check a lot before posting here. damm i missed it ..>

Comment: This is where an IDE comes handy ;o) I make errors like this all the time, but IDEA or PyCharm keeps nagging me until I fix them..